# Saving image element using splinter python

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

How can I save image picture to a file? i tried this way but i have an error.
the code is :

```
from splinter import Browser
import time

with Browser() as browser:
url = "https://password.gmx.com/"
browser.visit(url)
captcha=browser.find_by_id('recaptcha_challenge_container')
output = open ("image.jpg","wb")
output.write(captcha)
output.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional note to @alecxe's answer:
`splinter` doesn't have an interface for getting attribute of web element (i.e. `get_attribute` method).

Use the following code for getting `src` of captcha using `splinter`:

```py
script = "document.getElementById('recaptcha_challenge_image').src"
src = browser.evaluate_script(script)
```

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Jérémie!
To get `src` attribute value use following:

```
 src = browser.find_by_id('recaptcha_challenge_image')['src']
```

Comment: It does. browser.find_by_id('recaptcha_challenge_image')['src']

Comment: @Jérémie answer updated, however my answer is just additional note to another answer which was deleted :|

Comment: Yes, that other answer was deleted yesterday after I commented on it :) I hope it wasn't something I said!