# Saving an image using splinter python

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

I have an image in site and i want to save it to my computer but i cant find way.
the html relevent code is:

```
<div class="rfloatL text-field">
   <img src="/register/tb135/tb_getimage.php?uid=1450109984&start=" title style:="border:1-x solid;">
</div>
```

i tried those :

```
link=browser.find_by_css('border')
print link
print link[0]
link=browser.find_link_by_partial_href('register/tb135')
print link
print link[0]
link=browser.find_link_by partial_href('tb135')
print link
print link[0]
```

and the exeption is "EkementDoesNotExist".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252836/saving-image-element-using-splinter-python

Comment: its not the same... here i have only div class without id..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **find_by_tag("img")** to get the img element.